# Obscured digits while chat in timeout for mobile client

Tags: bug, design, chat, chat-timeout, mobile-chrome

> [image: digits]

As you can see, the top part of the countdown digits is obscured in mobile chat on Android Chrome.

Comment: @rene yes, it’s duplicate. But I’m suggesting to close old as dupe since my post has more obvious and animated image.